# R 3.5.2: Error in loading stock data from zoo

Tags: r

Trying to load Apple stock data from zoo. Getting the following error:

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'aapl.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: what command are you using? are you trying to read a file and that file doesn't exist? you need to give more information than this

Comment: After installing and loading the zoo package, I used the following command to load apple stock data:aapl<-read.zoo("aapl.csv", +   sep=",", header = TRUE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: does the aapl.csv file exist?

Comment: The zoo package (widely used) is supposed to have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What, exactly, are you trying to do?  The following script, below, works perfectly fine for me.

```
library(quantmod)
e <- new.env()
getSymbols("IBM;MSFT", env = e)
pframe <- do.call(merge, as.list(e))
head(pframe)
```

> head(pframe)

```
           IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted MSFT.Open MSFT.High
2007-01-03    97.18    98.40   96.26     97.27    9196800     70.11556     29.91     30.25
2007-01-04    97.25    98.79   96.88     98.31   10524500     70.86525     29.70     29.97
2007-01-05    97.60    97.95   96.91     97.42    7221300     70.22369     29.63     29.75
2007-01-08    98.50    99.50   98.35     98.90   10340000     71.29050     29.65     30.10
2007-01-09    99.08   100.33   99.07    100.07   11108200     72.13392     30.00     30.18
2007-01-10    98.50    99.05   97.93     98.89    8744800     71.28333     29.80     29.89
           MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume MSFT.Adjusted
2007-01-03    29.40      29.86    76935100      22.47883
2007-01-04    29.44      29.81    45774500      22.44119
2007-01-05    29.45      29.64    44607200      22.31321
2007-01-08    29.53      29.93    50220200      22.53152
2007-01-09    29.73      29.96    44636600      22.55411
2007-01-10    29.43      29.66    55017400      22.32826
```

Comment: Mark my answer as useful if it helped you. Thanks.